# jQuery: Get class with number and replace it

Tags: jquery, class, replace, switch-statement

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <input type=button class="foo abtn_1">
    <input type=button class="joe bbtn_2">
    <input type=button class="doe cbtn_2">
    <input type=button class="cool dbtn_1">
</div>
```

When I click a button, I need to **get the class of which contains the underscore (only) and change its number from 2 to 1.**

Currently I use this for each class:

```
$('.abtn_1').live('click', function () {
 $(this).switchClass('abtn_1','abtn_2');
});
$('.abtn_2').live('click', function () {
 $(this).switchClass('abtn_2','abtn_1');
});
$('.bbtn_1').live('click', function () {
 $(this).switchClass('bbtn_1','bbtn_2');
});
$('.bbtn_2').live('click', function () {
 $(this).switchClass('bbtn_2','bbtn_1');
});
// etc
```

So instead of having this so many times I thought of turning the whole thing in a line or two by *getting the underscore class and change its number accordingly of what number it is.*

I would imagine it would go something like:

```
var a =      // $(this).attr('class') without number and underscore
var b =      // This class number only
var c = $(this).attr('class'); // If I wanted to call it from 
                               // its parent $('#foo input'). 

if a contains number 1 {
    $(this).switchClass(c, a + '_1')
} else {
    $(this).switchClass(c, a + '_2')
};
```

Comment: You could use a regex to get the number, or a substring that contains just the last character. Btw: .live() is deprecated. I don't know which jQuery version you are using, but as of 1.7 you should use .on() instead of .live()

Comment: My client wants to use jQuery 1.6 of which on doesn't exists. Althought that wasnt my question. As for the regex, I am aware of its what I need to do. I just cant figure it otherwise I would be asking. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do the following:

1. Use one event handler for all the input elements
2. Replace the deprecated `.live()` with `.delegate()` (since OP using jQuery 1.6)
3. Find the `aaa_1` or `bbb_2` class name no matter where it is in the class name list

Here's the code:

```
​$(document).delegate('#foo input', 'click', ​function() {
    if (this.className.match(/_1(\s|$)/)) {
        this.className = this.className.replace("_1", "_2");
    } else {
        this.className = this.className.replace("_2", "_1");
    }
});​
```

When using `.delegate()` or `.on()`, you should pick a static parent element for the main jQuery object selector.  I used `document` here only because you didn't disclose the rest of your HTML, but it's better to use something closer to the actual target elements.

---

Here's another interesting way to do it using a custom replace function:

```
$(document).delegate('#foo input', 'click', function() {
    this.className = this.className.replace(/_(\d)(\s|$)/, function(str, p1, p2) {
        return("_" + (p1 == "1" ? "2" : "1") + p2);
    });
});​
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xgUzT/

Comment: I believe, `.on()` it's not on jQuery 1.6 :)

Comment: If you're still pre-jQuery 1.7, then you should be using `.delegate()` not `.live()`.  `.live()` has been deprecated for ALL versions of jQuery.

Comment: Works perfectly. Unfortunately my client uses jQuery 1.6 so I'll have to stick with live(). However, I am not using either since this will be in a function. Thank you

Comment: Hey, I'm not saying you're wrong, just that he said that he is using 1.6

Comment: @Nicosunshine - OK, I see that the 1.6 info was added in a comment.  It's not in the question which is what I saw when I wrote the answer.  Anyway, `.delegate()` is recommended for 1.6.  `.live()` can lead to performance issues with too many event handlers on the document object.  Both `.delegate()` and `.on()` allow you to pick a static parent element much closer to the target objects to prevent the performance bottleneck that `.live()` causes.

Comment: I added another option to my answer using a custom replace function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).delegate('#foo input', 'click', function () {
    var currentClass = this.className, //you can use $(this).attr("class") here if you want
    slicedClass = currentClass.slice(0,-2); //I'm asuming the _number is always at the end and with one digit, for better slicing use .replace(/_[0-9]+/, "");

   if(currentClass.search("_1") !== -1) {
       $(this).switchClass(currentClass, slicedClass + '_2');
   } else {
      $(this).switchClass(currentClass, slicedClass + '_1');
   }

});
```

tell me if that works for you.

**EDIT** 
Here is the working version of the fiddle you provided in the comment, do the changes you need to it  http://jsfiddle.net/uFLsx  :)

Comment: ow, one thing, you could add a `$` to the regex to only match at the end, like: `.replace(/(_[0-9]+)$/, "");`

Comment: It seems I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined which comes from the 3rd line, slice(0,-2)

Comment: ok, the className was undefined, try `console.log("Value of this", this);` and `console.log("Value of the class", this.className);` to see the values in the console

Comment: Okay so I found the error. It cannot pass the (this) into a function. This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/XWtSx/

Comment: Do I need to call sc(this) for the function ?

Comment: @jQuerybeast Last one, here is a working version, do the changes you need http://jsfiddle.net/uFLsx/

Comment: I have chosen jfriend00 answer since I find it better performance-wise. According to jsperf, search is up to 60% slower than jfriend00's answer. Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```js
$('#foo input').live('click', function () {
    var from_class = "";
    var to_class = "";

    $.each($(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/),function(i,c){
        var matches = c.match(/(\w+_)(\d)/i);               
        if(matches != null)
        {
            from_class = matches[0];
            from_number = matches[2];
            to_number = (matches[2] == '1')?'2':'1';
            to_class = matches[1]+to_number;
            return false;   // Stop the loop since we found the class.
        }
    });
    if(from_class != "" && to_class != "")
    {
        $(this).switchClass(from_class,to_class);
    }
});
```

And like Johannes Klauß said, use .on() instead of .live() if you are using the new version of jQuery .